# How can I print a unicode character from its name?

Tags: go, unicode

In Python, I can use \N to print unicode characters.

```
 print('\N{White Smiling Face}')
```

Will print ☺

Is there an way to do the same thing in Go? Couldn't find anything in `unicode` or [x/text](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text).

Comment: That's not a native feature of Go. You'd need to find a mapping of names to code points and use it to translate.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. Is there a way in Go to get this mapping?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... You'll have to find a mapping somewhere, in some format, and either read it at runtime or maybe use a generator at compile time to convert it to something like a `map[string]rune`.

Comment: Actually [`x/text/unicode/runenames`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames) has a mapping from rune to name, just not the backward direction. Here's the official list of runes and names, it's a simple CSV file which you can parse and build a map from name to rune: [Unicode Data](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).